# Ubuntu can't install an older version of a package

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

When I try to do an apt-get install, I keep getting an error: `Depends: libgtk-3-common (= 3.4.1-0ubuntu1) but 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.4 is to be installed`

when I run `sudo apt-get -f install`, I get several `dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'XXX' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.`

then

```
Preparing to replace libgtk-3-bin 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 (using .../libgtk-3-bin_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.4_i386.deb) ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches to /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches.gtk2 by libgtk-3-bin'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches.gtk2' with
  different file `/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches', not allowed
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk-3-bin_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk-3-bin_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm not sure why it's complaining about a newer version of a package, but any help would be appreciated

Comment: To install an older version: `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-common=3.4.1-0ubuntu1`

Comment: Thanks for putting it in the right forum...

When I try to downgrade to 3.4.1, I get the error `Depends: libgtk-3-common (= 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.4) but 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed`